# Can a font omit the space character?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, fonts, whitespace

I'm working on a font detection library that needs to be very, very small, suitable for including inline on every page of a website. I've already gotten it pretty small (417 bytes gzipped). You can check it out at [the Github repo](https://github.com/dwighthouse/onfontready).

Upon further thinking, I can reduce the size of the library significantly again (around another 10%) if I can make a few basic assumptions:

- It is impossible to define a working font file (for browsers, anyway) without a [space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm) character/definition.
- OR, if such a `space`-omitting font could be created, that all modern browsers and IE9+ will choose the fallback font's `space` character when a `space` character is needed. That is, there is otherwise nothing special about the `space` character in terms of font-fallback.
- And, tangentially, all modern browsers and IE9+ will have a different width for the `space` character in `serif` and `monospace` generic fonts provided by the browser (probable, but I will need to test further).

I just attempted to explicitly define a font without a `space` character using [FontSquirrel's font generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). This was done by explicitly omitting the space from the selected Subset and disabling the 'Fix Missing Glyphs' for `space`. FontSquirrel still generated a font with a `space` character with a width differing from both `serif` and `monospace`.

I understand that some languages do not have a `space` character in the traditional sense, but due to the nature of font file formats and definitions, I do not think that fonts tailored to such a language could or would omit a `space` character.

If these assumptions all hold, the library could remove the need to support custom text checking and reduce the number of tests from 3 to 2, also speeding up the library and reducing its memory usage. The new size would be around 380 bytes or less when gzipped.

So how about it, font experts? Is it possible to define a valid font without a `space` character definition? If there is such a font, can you provide an example?

Comment: I have no idea regarding what you ask, but I do suggest you ask yourself this: do you really care? 40 bytes? The odds of this making any difference whatsoever are so slim it's not worth your time...

Comment: 2nd request in the browser should already come from cache so the ~40 byte savings will likely only apply to the first request. Since most sites also download large JS libraries, it's not likely that the total ~500 bytes would matter much, let alone the possible savings of this optimization.

Comment: It matters because the sites I am building are designed to be fully inline. All HTML, CSS, JS, SVGs, and some images will be inlined, leaving only font files and larger images to require an extra http request. As long as the total size of all of the inlining is less than 14 kb or so (gzipped), it can be delivered in a single http request, and can be even more efficient than caching those resources. 40 gzipped bytes is a lot under these conditions.

Comment: I also care for the same reason people climb Mount Everest. There is no objective reason to go there, and it is a very difficult task to do. Yet people do it anyway in order to prove it can be done, and to test both themselves and the limits of human potential. So too with the smallest possible code to accomplish a task. Think of this as a code golfing challenge, which are also of little practical use, but they are a good exercise.

Comment: short answer: yes. longer answer: http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/the_smallest_font (particularly salient is that gzipping doesn't make the most sense if this needs to be loaded for some kind of immediacy testing)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Interesting data. It seems that, for a specially constructed font that does not contain a `space` character, the glyph used will indeed fall to the fallback font. Do you know of any non-experimental fonts that do not contain a `space` character?

Comment: None spring to mind, because for a normal font not having a space makes no sense. The ASCII range of Unicode is trivially supported in any real font creation application, so even for a not-latin language there tends to be support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that while it is possible, it is virtually unheard-of to create a font without a space character. Even icon font services appear to include it. Other than a [special case for a font detection library](http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/the_smallest_font/), there are no known fonts that omit the space character.

This research led to an improvement to my [onfontready library](https://github.com/dwighthouse/onfontready/). Details [here](https://github.com/dwighthouse/onfontready/blob/master/docs/howItWorks.md#space-character). Thanks to [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) for his contributions.